# Stopping re-render in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

so I know I can use useMemo() or shouldComponentUpdate() to stop unnecessary re-renders in React, but I'm unsure as to why things aren't working well in my case. I very much appreciate any help

To keep it short and sweet, I have a list that I want to render out, and am pushing child components into that list that I'm slicing to paginate. I do not want the child components (Member) to update when I paginate the entire list, but I do want the list to still be sliceable in order to paginate through the different team members. Currently, when I try to paginate while using the existing setup below, it does not work. However, if I remove shouldComponentUpdate(), it will paginate, but also trigger a re-render of the child components. I simply want the slice targets to change and render difference indices of the list without causing re-renders of each Member.

Sorry if that was confusing to understand- totally makes sense in my head, but probably not on paper.

Below is only the necessary code:

```
const BuildTeams = ({team}) => {

const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0)

const teamList = []

for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
teamList.push(
   <div key={someUniqueID}>
     <Member />
   </div>
   );
 }

// Function used to change state/paginate
function handleChangeIndex(targetInd) {
const target = currentIndex + targetInd;
if (target >= teamList.length) {
    setCurrentIndex(0)
} else setCurrentIndex(target)
}

return <div>
{teamList.slice(currentIndex,currentIndex+1)}
{teamLength > 1 && <button id="arrow" onClick={()=>{handleChangeIndex(1)}}>VIEW MORE/></button>}
</div>;
};

export default BuildTeams;
```

The child component:

```
class Member extends Component {

shouldComponentUpdate() {
  return false;
}

render() {
 return (
   <div>
     <img src={`/images/img_${Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 1}.jpg`}/>
   </div>
 )
}

export default Member;
```

Comment: Remember to properly indent your code. And the normal way would be to copy your code into your editor, and tell it to autoformat, but when you do that with the code you're showing, you'll instead get a number of errors due to bad syntax, so please also fix those. And of course on a React note: I don't see you use `key` attributes for the elements you're pushing into `teamList`: you definitely need those if you want React to do its job properly.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for the reply! There actually is a key when being pushed, I just tried to remove anything I deemed unnecessary for the post to avoid clutter for anyone reading it. As far as indentation is concerned, it got all messed up when I c+p'd it into the textfield here.

Comment: But adding [keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) is the answer to your question...

Comment: React keys are generally pretty necessary when rendering lists/arrays to JSX.  Why are you creating a local `teamList` copy of the `teams` prop when you can `teams.slice(....).map(....)` in a more functional way?

Comment: @DrewReese great point! Thank you for the reply :)

Comment: No need for the slice even, `map` already synchronously  generates a new array. That said: even if you're reducing your code to a [mcve], don't strip "necessary" boilerplate. Minimal doesn't mean "as little code as possible", it's "as little code as possible while still doing everything correctly, except for that problem you're having" =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The slice is for the pagination, not just for creating a new array reference, i.e. `.slice(index, index + paginationSize)`.

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for all of the replies! Following up, even after adding keys in the parent, the list does appear to actually paginate now, however every time I do, a new random image is generated in the child and I would love for the random image chosen to stick as I paginate in the parent. Any ideas on a fix for that?

Comment: John, you are generating a new image source each time `Member` renders with `<img src={\`/images/img_${Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 1}.jpg\`}/>`. Move `/images/img_${Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 1}.jpg` into local state so it persists, or move it into the parent where the array is generated so it persists with the state there.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks again- tried moving it into state with no luck. I think the issue is that the direct parent is changing state, and shouldComponentUpdate() is not working properly because of it? I would move the image chosen to parent state, but that would also change every time the parent re-renders. I figured this would definitely work

Comment: Ok. do you mind updating your question then to include a more accurate/representative [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see more clearly what your code is doing?

Comment: Sure @DrewReese - definitely tried my best there. It's been updated. At its core, the only real issue persisting is the fact that I would love my Member component to not re-render as its parent state (BuildTeams) changes. Not only do I want this to occur for performance reasons, but it seems to re-choose a random image and re-mounts my component, even though shouldComponentUpdate is set to false. I figured that once I pushed those child components into the teamList array, its properties would stay the same, even though the slice value is changing.

Comment: Can you please still fix the indentation and (now new) syntax errors in your first code block? SO lets you copy-paste just fine after auto-formatting in your IDE/VS Code/etc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure everytime a parent rerenders, all of its children (recursively) rerender no matter what

Comment: @Samathingamajig that's what im figuring is the issue here- just trying to figure out a workaround

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans absolutely! one minute

Comment: What is rendering `BuildTeams` and passing a `team` prop value? Is `team` the "state" that is being updated?

Comment: Effectively: is there a _real_ [mcve] here, that folks can run to see this problem manifest? Because the length of this comment thread is evidence enough that this post needs one. Create a simple `App` that loads in a BuildTeams component (although that's not a name a component should have. `buildTeams` would be a function, `Teams` would be the resulting component), and a button that updates things such that it reproduces the problem. Nothing explains a problem as clearly as "the minimal code required to _reproduce_ the problem".